# Excel VBA - How do you set outer bound of 1 dimensional array using const or var? Is their a work around?

Tags: vba, excel

How do you set the outer bound of an array like this?

```
var(1 To numJobs)
```

I error out at line 14:

```
Const numJobs As Integer = Worksheets("Optimization").Range("B62").Value
```

I want to create one dimensional arrays to be able to set values during the do while loops:

```
Dim loopNum, finishedNum, neededQuantity(1 To numJobs), _
finishedQuantity(1 To numJobs), remainingQuantity(1 To numJobs) As Integer
```

Here is all my code for this section:

```
'Set number of Jobs into a variable
Set numofJobs = Worksheets("Optimization").Range("B62")
MsgBox numofJobs

'Create finished Boolean:   Set to False to indicate the Optimizer has not       finished and to continue loop
'                           Set to True to indicate when the Optimizer has       finished to exit do while loop
Dim finished As Boolean
finished = False

'declare 1 char integers for use in For Loops
Dim i As Integer

'Declare const variables for looper
Const numJobs As Integer = Worksheets("Optimization").Range("B62").Value

'Declare int variables to hold row, column, and other quanity information
Dim loopNum, finishedNum, neededQuantity(1 To numJobs), _
finishedQuantity(1 To numJobs), remainingQuantity(1 To numJobs) As Integer

'Set loopNum to 1 because the looper always begins on loop 1
loopNum = 1

'Store the Column Number for Finished Quantity. This is a reference during the Optimization
'process when attempting to assess if the loop needs to put molds from a job on a given loop
finishedNum = 81

'Begin Optimizer
Do While finished = False

'For each job; from the first job to your last job
For i = 1 To numofJobs.Value

    'Current Job Needed Quantity is found in Column D = 4, in the fifth row   + i
    neededQuantity(i) = Cells(5 + i, 4).Value
    finishedQuantity(i) = Cells(5 + 1, finishedNum).value

    MsgBox neededQuantity(i)

    Stop
    'Set remainingQuantity for current job
    'remainingQuanity = neededQuantity - finishedQuantity
    remainingQuantity(i) = neededQuantity(i) - finishedQuantity(i)

'Cells(5 + i, 10 + loopNum).Value = 1

Next i
```

Comment: Const. needs to be assigned a value which is known at compile time: you can't assign something known only at run time

Answer (score 0):

`Dim Var(1 To 14) As Long` declares a fixed sized array Var with elements 1 to 14.

`Dim Var() As Long` declares a dynamic array which will be sized at run time.

`ReDim Var(1 To 14)` sets the initial size of Var so it has elements 1 to 14.  It you later discover this is not enough elements `ReDim Preserve Var(1 to 28)` effectively adds another 14 elements to array Var.

I have used literals in my `Redim` statements but both the lower and upper bounds can be variables: `ReDim Var(Lb To Ub)`.  The lower bound can be negative, zero, one or more.  The upper bound must be greater or equal to the lower bound.

Please note that in:

```
Dim loopNum, finishedNum, neededQuantity(1 To numJobs), _
finishedQuantity(1 To numJobs), remainingQuantity(1 To numJobs) As Integer
```

only remainingQuantity will be of type Integer.  All the rest will be of type Variant.

Consider `Set numofJobs = Worksheets("Optimization").Range("B62")`.  As Tim says, you cannot declare `numOfJobs` as a constant.  `Set` is only used is the variable is an object such as a range or a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Got it...Here is my code. I used the dynamic array.

```
'Dim as dynamic arrays adn set bounds
Dim neededQuantity(), _
finishedQuantity(), _
remainingQuantity(), _
maxMolds() As Variant

'Set loopNum to 1 because the looper always begins on loop 1
loopNum = 1

'Store the Column Number for Finished Quantity. This is a reference during the Optimization
'process when attempting to assess if the loop needs to put molds from a job on a given loop
finishedNum = 81

'Begin Optimizer
Do While finished = False

'For each job; from the first job to your last job
For i = 1 To (numofJobs.Value)

    currentRow = 5 + i

    'Current Job Needed Quantity is found in Column D = 4, in the fifth row + i
    ReDim Preserve neededQuantity(i)
    neededQuantity(i) = Cells(currentRow, 4).Value

    'Current Job Needed Quantity is found in Column CC = 81, in the fifth row + i
    ReDim Preserve finishedQuantity(i)
    finishedQuantity(i) = Cells(currentRow, finishedNum).Value

    'Set remainingQuantity for current job
    'remainingQuanity = neededQuantity - finishedQuantity
    ReDim Preserve remainingQuantity(i)
    remainingQuantity(i) = (neededQuantity(i) - finishedQuantity(i))

    'Set available molds be job
    ReDim Preserve maxMolds(i)
    maxMolds(i) = Cells(currentRow, 7).Value

    'If the ramining quantity needed is greater than the maximum amount of molds
    If remainingQuantity(i) >= maxMolds(i) Then
            'then set the cell equal to the max molds
            Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value = maxMolds(i)
        Else
            'else set the cell equal to the remaining Quantity of molds
            Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value = remainingQuantity(i)
    End If

    'Store the value for number of parts in this loop in the variable loopQuantity
    loopQuantity = Cells(60, 10 + loopNum).Value
    If loopQuantity > maxMoldsPerLoop.Value Then
            maxQuantityReached = True
            Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value = Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value - (loopQuantity - maxMoldsPerLoop)
        Else
            'continue
            maxQuantityReached = False
    End If

    If maxQuantityReached = True Then
        Exit For
    End If

    If Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value = ""
    End If

Next i


'Add 1 to the current loop number to prepare the optimizer for the next loop
loopNum = loopNum + 1


'stop loop for editting
finished = True

'When Optimizer has no more parts to add and all jobs have been optimized
If Range("CC62") = 0 Then
        'finished is equal to True because we are ready to exit the optimizer
        finished = True
    Else
        'if no, then we still have parts to put on the loop and optimize
        'set finished to False because we need to continue or repeat the Do While loop above
        finished = False
        currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
End If

'When the code reaches this, it goes back up to the Do While Line
Loop
```